# Список разнородных виджетов

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Пытаюсь соорудить форму с настройками.
Для пользователя это должно выглядеть как список, состоящий из label'ов, checkbox'ов, spinbox'ов:

> описание настройки
>   настройка 1: (checkbox)
>   настройка 2: (10)
>   настройка 3: (checkbox)

Попробовал сделать класс-интерфейс, унаследованный от `QWidget` - `PageConfigItem`, от него будут наследоваться реализации: `PageConfigItem_Bool`, `PageConfigItem_Int` и т.д.

Дальше надо определить массив с этими элементами и положить его на форму.

Я в принципе сомневаюсь, что подход правильный. Задача-то стандартная, должен быть стандартный контейнер. Как-то очень объемно сейчас получается.

Код вот такой:

```
class PageConfigItem
        : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual ~PageConfigItem() {}
signals:
    void Changed (int32_t setting, int32_t value);
public slots:
    virtual void SetValue (int32_t value) = 0;
protected:
    PageConfigItem (QWidget * parent) :
        QWidget (parent) {}
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(PageConfigItem, "PageConfigItem")



class PageConfigItem_Bool :
        public PageConfigItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(PageConfigItem)
public:
    explicit PageConfigItem_Bool (
            const QString & name_,
            QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~PageConfigItem_Bool ()
    {
        qDebug() << "PageConfigItem_Bool destructor";
    }
public slots:
    void SetValue (int32_t value);
private:
    QCheckBox chkbox;
};

PageConfigItem_Bool::PageConfigItem_Bool (
            const QString &name_, QWidget *parent) :
    PageConfigItem (parent)
{
    qDebug() << "PageConfigItem_Bool constuct" << name_;
    chkbox.setText (name_);
}

void PageConfigItem_Bool::SetValue(int32_t value)
{    chkbox.setChecked (value != 0);    }
```

Comment: нет, qDebug() работает прекрасно. Второй вопрос закрываем - сам дурак, при использовании зачем-то вызывал layout->addItem() вместо addWidget(). Ручное приведение типов - зло, это во всех букварях написано :-)

Comment: Ну Ваш подход выглядит нормально, никаких стандартных средств реализации подобного нет, а как они могут быть? Если стандартно, то можно просто напихать разных виджетов в разметку(layout), но Вам ведь надо какое-то поведение для каждого элемента, так? Если так, то надо наследоваться, если нет — то просто разместить все элементы в разметке и ловить от них нужные сигналы.

Answer (score 3):

Нет большой необходимости в том, чтобы начать создавать собственную иерархическую систему классов. Окно настроек, содержащее произвольные виджеты, может быть реализовано посредством использования `QItemEditorFactory`.

Обозначенный класс имеет статический метод `QItemEditorFactory::defaultFactory()`, который можно вызвать из любого места в своём коде и создать виджет, подходящий для редактирования того или иного типа данных:

```
const QItemEditorFactory *factory = QItemEditorFactory::defaultFactory();

// Указатель на виджет-родитель, который можно присвоить вновь
// создаваемому виджету прямо на месте, так сказать,
// не отходя далеко от кассы.
QWidget *parent = ...;    

// Создать поле ввода для чисел.
QWidget *wdg1 = factory->createEditor(QVariant::Int, parent);
QSpinBox *sbox = qobject_cast<QSpinBox*>(wdg1);

// Создать поле ввода для строк.
QWidget *wdg2 = factory->createEditor(QVariant::String, parent);
QLineEdit *ledit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(wdg2);
```

Разумеется, вовсе не обязательно приводить базовый тип виджета к его истинному типу ради того, чтобы, например, установить текущее значение перед тем, как пользователь начнёт его редактировать. Для этого достаточно воспользоваться возможностями метаобъектной системы Qt:

```
// Создать поле ввода для чисел и установить значение по умолчанию.
QWidget *wdg1 = factory->createEditor(QVariant::Int, parent);
wdg1->setProperty("value", 12345);

// Создать поле ввода для строк и установить значение по умолчанию.
QWidget *wdg2 = factory->createEditor(QVariant::String, parent);
wdg2->setProperty("text", "tra-ta-ta");
```

Если в силу каких-то причин неизвестно наименование свойства произвольного виджета, которое пользователь будет редактировать, то можно поступить следующим образом:

```
void setWidgetUserProperty(QWidget *wdg, const QVariant &value) {
    const QByteArray name
        = wdg->metaObject()->userProperty().name();

    if(name.isEmpty() == false) {
        if(value.isValid() == true)
            wdg->setProperty(name, value);
    }
}

// Создать поле ввода для чисел и установить значение по умолчанию.
QWidget *wdg1 = factory->createEditor(QVariant::Int, parent);
setWidgetUserProperty(wdg1, 12345);

// Создать поле ввода для строк и установить значение по умолчанию.
QWidget *wdg2 = factory->createEditor(QVariant::String, parent);
setWidgetUserProperty(wdg2, "tra-ta-ta");
```

Qt поддерживает несколько типов данных, для которых фабрика, используемая по умолчанию, может создавать отдельные виджеты:

```
bool      QComboBox
double    QDoubleSpinBox
int       QSpinBox
QDate     QDateEdit
QDateTime QDateTimeEdit
QPixmap   QLabel
QString   QLineEdit
QTime     QTimeEdit
```

Однако этот стандартный набор нисколько не ограничивает возможность добавления собственных типов. Например, требуется создать виджет в виде раскрывающегося списка, поддерживающего установку/получение цвета `QColor` в качестве текущего значения:

```
class ColorComboBox : public QComboBox {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor USER true)

    public:
        ColorComboBox(QWidget *widget = Q_NULLPTR) {}

        QColor color() const;
        void setColor(const QColor &color);

};

QColor ColorComboBox::color() const {
    return qvariant_cast<QColor>(itemData(currentIndex()
        , Qt::DecorationRole));
}

void ColorComboBox::setColor(const QColor &color) {
    setCurrentIndex(findData(color, int(Qt::DecorationRole)));
}
```

Теперь, зарегистрировать и использовать новый тип виджетов не составит труда:

```
QItemEditorFactory *factory = new QItemEditorFactory(this);

QItemEditorCreatorBase *color_cbox_creator
    = new QStandardItemEditorCreator<ColorComboBox>();

factory->registerEditor(QVariant::Color, color_cbox_creator);

QItemEditorFactory::setDefaultFactory(factory);
```

Новая фабрика подменит собой ту, что ранее использовалась по умолчанию, но также будет доступна по `QItemEditorFactory::defaultFactory()`.